# Registration in Django with sending by smtp qr code for 2fa

Tags: django, smtp

Threw django project on hosting, but no domain yet, front on react, run locally. The problem is that smtp does not send a letter to mail.
Here are the settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

views

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
mail_subject = 'TOKEN'
message = render_to_string('emails/account_activation_email.html', {
   'user': user,
   'qr_code': device.config_url,
})
to_email = serializer.validated_data['email']
email = EmailMessage(
    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
)
email.content_subtype = "html"
email.send()
```

I assume that the letter is not sent because there is no domain and protocol http, because locally everything worked. Maybe someone had such a problem, if the domain with ssl purchase it will pass ?